# Serialize not sending all data from form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, serialization

I recently was introduced to sending form values in my `ajax` calls with `serialize()`. It is working for the most part, except for one case.

The div `proposal-type`contains selected or unselected input checkboxes. The value was only sending over as one of the selections. So, in a nutshell, I am unsure of how to send over a variable in my data, along with the serialize.

I tried:

```
var datastring = $('#proposal-form').serialize();
data: {
    "type": type},
    datastring
,
```

and

```
var datastring = $('#proposal-form').serialize();
data: 
    "type": type,
    datastring
,
```

But no luck with either. Below is more of the code. Does anyone have any ideas of how I can do this?

```
<form method="POST" action="" id="proposal-form">
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="text" id="proposal-name" name="proposal_name" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Name *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="email" id="proposal-email" name="proposal_email" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Email *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="tel" id="proposal-phone" name="proposal_phone" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Phone *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="text" id="proposal-location" name="proposal_location" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Location *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input"><input type="text" id="proposal-company" name="proposal_company" class="proposal-input" placeholder="Company *"></div>
    <div class="panel-input">
    <div id="proposal-type" class="proposal-input"></div>
        <div id="proposal-type-drop">
                <label class="drop-item">A<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type" class="drop-item-input" value="A"></label>
                <label class="drop-item">B<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type" class="drop-item-input" value="B"></label>
                <label class="drop-item">C<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type" class="drop-item-input" value="C"></label>
            </div>
    </div>
    <textarea class="proposal-text" id="proposal-description" name="proposal_description" placeholder="Project Details *"></textarea>
</form>

submitHandler: function(form) {
        event.preventDefault();
        /*var proposal_name = $('#proposal-name').val();
        var proposal_email = $('#proposal-email').val();
        var proposal_phone = $('#proposal-phone').val();
        var proposal_location = $('#proposal-location').val();
        var proposal_company = $('#proposal-company').val();*/
        var type = $('.drop-item-input:checked').map(function() {
                        return $(this).val();
                    }).get().join(', ');
        //var proposal_description = $('#proposal-description').val();
        var datastring = $('#proposal-form').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            url: "php/proposal-send.php", 
            type: "POST",
            data: 
                /*"proposal_name": proposal_name,
                "type": type,*/
                datastring
            ,
```

Comment: Why not use json?

Comment: @bigbounty Not sure how to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit multiple values for a checkbox you need to add `[]` to their names so their values will be submitted as an array.

You can also manually increment the array indexes by placing an integer inbetween the square brackets.

Not adding the bracket notation basically overwrites the value of the checkbox for each subsequent checked input with the same name.

Without brackets the querystring looks like this:

```
prop-type=A&prop-type=B&prop-type=c
```

With the brackets comes out like this:

```
prop-type[]=A&prop-type[]=B&prop-type[]=c
```

Comment: So I would just do `name="prop-type[]"` to the html?

Comment: If `adding the bracket notation basically overwrites the value of the checkbox for each subsequent checked input with the same name.` then why would it be the right thing to do? Wouldn't that be counter productive?

Comment: @Paul Your quote does not include the first word of the sentence: `Not`...

Comment: Do I have to include the array brackets in the `$_POST` in the php variable? `$proposal_type = trim(htmlspecialchars($_POST['prop-type[]']));` That is throwing an error.

Comment: @Paul no it will give you array result without `[]` like `$_POST['prop-type']`

Comment: @Paul No, the bracket notation creates an array for your PHP script;  `var_dump($_POST['prop-type']);` will show you the structure of your array. In general a good way to debug what your PHP script is receiving is to do a `var_dump($_POST);` and look at your AJAX response in the Network Panel of your Developer Tools, or put in your code to `console.log()` the response.

Comment: The network > header result of my console is showing : `prop-type[]:A
prop-type[]:B`, which is what I selected, but the value the php is showing is just the text `Array`. With .. `$proposal_type = $_POST['prop-type'];`

Comment: Try `print_r($_POST['prop-type'])` for array results in php, instead of `echo`

Comment: Array ( [0] => A [1] => B ) 
Notice: Array to string conversion in /php/proposal-send.php on line 70
Message has been sent

Comment: Whenever I do `$proposal_type = print_r($_POST['prop-type']);`, I just get the number one to print where every I put the variable.

Comment: @Paul Try `var_dump($_POST);` on its' own line, not as part of a variable assignment. When something isn't working it's best to start at the beginning and walk through the process only after each step is understood.

Comment: @Jasper When printing `$_POST['prop-type'];` the correct values are sending through. The issue I am having is how to apply these values in a variable to use further down the page for an email output. I will call it like `$proposal_type` and then get the #1 or Array wording.

Comment: @Paul You may want to open a different question for that issue. But if you assign `$_POST['prop-type']` to a variable called `$proposal_type` then try to concoct a string like this: `$someString = "Look at my proposal types!!1 " . $proposal_type;` then you're trying to mix variable types and it'll go badly. You need to convert the `$proposal_type` array into a string. This can be accomplished using `implode`: http://php.net/implode

Comment: @Jasper Thanks for the tip! The implode method worked painlessly. I wasn't aware of it.

Answer (score 1):

try changing your input `checkboxes` name to `array`

**This:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type" class="drop-item-input" value="A">
```

**To This:**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="prop-type[]" class="drop-item-input" value="A">
```

Also, you can use below code to send extra data with `serialize()` data

```
$.ajax({
    type : 'POST',
    url : 'url',
    data : $('#form').serialize() + "&par1=1&par2=2&par3=232"
}
```